# Correct proposition? Let $G$ be a group and $N\lhd G$. Prove or disprove that if $G/N$ and $N$ are p-groups then $G$ is a p-group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Correct proposition? Let $G$ be a group and $N\lhd G$. Prove or disprove that if $G/N$ and $N$ are p-groups then $G$ is a p-group.

So I disproved it, but in my homework grading they said it's actually correct (not providing a proof..). I can't see what went wrong with my refute:

Let $G=\mathbb Z_{45}$. Let $N=\mathbb Z_9$, so $N$ is normal and is a p-group. $[G:N]=5$ therefore $G/N$ s also a p-group. As we can see $G$ isn't.

Did I do anything wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the intended meaning is the following. *Let $p$ be a prime. Let $G$ be a group and $N\lhd G$. Prove or disprove that if $G/N$ and $N$ are $p$-groups then $G$ is a $p$-group.* In other words, $N$ and $G/N$ are $p$-groups for the same prime $p$.

Comment: Yes, to underline Andreas's point, p is assumed to be a fixed prime in this question.

Comment: You can say that the trick is that $p=p$. :-)

Comment: The question is so badly worded that it is difficult to guess what the intended meaning is. I don't think it at all clear that $p$ is intended to be a fixed prime. It could be a generic use of "$p$-group".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean the groups are $p$-groups for the same $p$, not just groups of prime power order.  In your counterexample, $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$ is a $3$-group and $\mathbb{Z}_{45}/\mathbb{Z}_9$ is a $5$-group.

Answer (score 2):

I think, as some of the commentators suggest, that you have to assume "$p$" represents the same prime for both $N$ and $G/N$.  Indeed, I assume so . . .

This being said, we can argue as follows:  since $N \triangleleft G$, the collection of cosets of $N$, $\{ gN \mid g \in G \}$  forms the group $ 
G/N$ under the multiplucation of cosets

$(g_1 N)(g_2 N) = g_1 g_2 N, \tag{1}$

for all $g_1, g_2 \in G$; this is an easily verified and well-known fact.  If $G/N$ is a $p$-group for some prime $p$, then we have, for any $g \in G$, a positive integer $n$ such that $(gN)^{p^n} = N$, since $N = e_G N$ is the identity coset in the group $G/N$, where $e_G$ is the identity element of $G$.  Now by (1),

$N = (gN)^{p^n} = g^{p^n} N, \tag{2}$

which implies $g^{p^n} \in N$.  Since $N$ is a $p$-group, with the same "$p$" as $G/N$, we have $(g^{p^n})^{p^m} = e_G$ for some positive integer $m$.  But

$e_G = (g^{p^n})^{p^m} = g^{p^n p^m} = g^{p^{n + m}}, \tag{3}$

so that we see

$g^{p^{n + m}} = e_G, \tag{4}$

for all $g \in G$, though the power of $p$, $n + m$, may depend upon $g \in G$.  In any event, this shows that $G$ is a $p$-group.  Provided, of course, $N$ and $G/N$ have the same $p$!  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Adding tiny detail: we want to show order of $g$ is power of $p$ (including $1$). $g^{p^{n+m}}=e_G$ implies $|g|\mid p^{n+m}$. Thus $|g|$ is power of $p$.